# Grammatically correct alternative for 'Awaiting your confirmation'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrase-usage

While typing a confirmation email, I use 'Awaiting your confirmation', which is an incomplete sentence. What's the grammatically correct alternative?

P.S: I don't want to use the subject, so 'We are awaiting your confirmation' is not an option.

Comment: 'Awaiting your confirmation' is okay as a set formula. If not, use the more traditional form without insisting that you won't use it but want help.

Answer (score 1):

"*Awaiting your confirmation*" is in fact short for "We are  awaiting your confirmation" (or "I am awaiting your confirmation.") The short form is fine as it stands.  In an informal medium such as email, incomplete sentences are quite acceptable, and it is at least arguable that "*Awaiting your confirmation*"  is **not** incomplete because subject and verb are clearly implied, and there is no ambiguity. But a variation on the sentence suggested by FumbleFingers, specifically "**We await your confirmation.**" ought to b fully acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326787/grammatically-correct-alternative-for-awaiting-your-confirmation#comment616182_326787) user 
[FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers) answered:

> You choose to define your current wording as "an incomplete sentence", but that strongly implies you're assuming a valid sentence must contain *at least* a subject and a verb. I suppose *in principle* you could avoid using ***we*** by going for a passive ***Your response is awaited***, but there's every chance you'll confuse and/or irritate the recipient. Just forget the pointless continuous verb form and equally pointless desire to avoid pronouns, and end with ***We await your response***.

Comment: The OP specifically said including a subject was not an option, so "We await your response" doesn't work.

Comment: More exactly, the OP wrote "*: I don't want to use the subject*" but did not explain why. @r FumbleFingers is suggesting that this desire is a mistake and the subject be used anyway.  Yosef Baskin made a similar suggestion n a comment.